# Spark-shell behave different from Spark submit

Tags: serialization, apache-spark

I use the `RDD[T]`'s `fitler` method. When I execute with `spark-shell` I got `task not serializable` exception.

```
trait MyBase extends Serializable
object Type1 extends MyBase
object Type2 extends MyBase



object TestShell {


  def readline(line:String) = {
    if (line.contains( "scroll" )) Type1 else Type2
  }

  def main(args:Array[String])(implicit sc:org.apache.spark.SparkContext) = {

    val data = sc.textFile( "D:\\work\\myfile" )

    val parsed = data map (readline)

    parsed filter (_ == Type1) take 100 foreach println

  }
}
```

However when I create a `SparkContext` in the program (Or use spark submit) with local mode, it works well.

```
object MainDesktop {

  val appName = "newApp"
  val master = "local"

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
  implicit val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {

    TestShell.main(args)(sc)

  }

}
```

Is it a bug of Spark Shell?

Comment: I believe so. Here is a simplification of possibly the same thing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762964/task-not-serializable-when-using-object-in-repl

Answer (score 0):

So your going to run into task not seizable all over the place when you try to factor code out into reusable objects. Generally you won't hit all of them until you run in yarn-client or yarn-cluster mode. When your running in local mode are you using local or local[*] for your master?

Comment: I run it with yarn-client