# Task not serializable when using object in REPL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, closures

So, another SO question prompted me to try the following:

```
object Foo{
  def f = 1
}

sc.parallelize(List(1)).map(x=>{
  val myF = Foo.f _
  x + myF()
}
```

Which works, but the following does not:

```
object Foo{
  def f = 1
  def run(rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]) = rdd.map(x=>{
    val myF = Foo.f _
    x + myF()
  }
}

Foo.run(sc.parallelize(List(1)))
```

I will take a deeper look at the serialization stack tomorrow when I can remove the mess of the REPL output. But, this should be the same thing. Why does one way yell and the other does not.

Comment: Are you trying this on the REPL?

Comment: The second way would have to serialize `Foo` the object instance, while the first would not. So that could be the difference.

Comment: Yeah, it's recursively trying to serialize the same instance of `Foo`. But why? `def run()` is a method it shouldn't be touched during serialization, right?

Comment: @maasg Yes, I will create a standalone in a little and update if anything changes based on that.

Comment: @JustinPihony the REPL wraps code in classes and you get some funky side effects from that.  e.g. case classes cannot be used as keys: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2620

Comment: @maasg Go ahead and make that the answer if you want and I will accept. Otherwise I will just close it. I just tested in a stand alone app and it works fine.

Comment: @JustinPihony "you get some funky side effects" -- I wouldn't call that a proper answer :-)