# Type mismatch with identical types in Spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, read-eval-print-loop, type-mismatch

I have build a scripting workflow around the spark-shell but I'm often vexed by bizarre type mismatches (probably inherited from the scala repl) occuring with identical found and required types. The following example illustrates the problem. Executed in paste mode, no problem

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)


import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
case class C(S:String)
def f(r:RDD[C]): String = "hello"
val in = sc.parallelize(List(C("hi")))
f(in)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
defined class C
f: (r: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[C])String
in: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[C] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:13
res0: String = hello
```

but

```
scala> f(in)
<console>:29: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[C]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[C]
              f(in)
                ^
```

There are related discussion [about the scala repl](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/lmpM74EWB3E) and [about the spark-shell](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Simple-Scala-code-not-working-in-Spark-shell-repl/td-p/16564)
but the mentioned [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1199) seems unrelated (and resolved) to me.

This problem causes serious problems for writing passable code to be executed interactively in the repl, or causes to lose most of the advantage of working in a repl to begin with. Is there a solution? (And/or is it a known issue?)

**Edits:**

Problems occured with spark 1.2 and 1.3.0. Test made on spark 1.3.0 using scala 2.10.4

It seems that, at least in the test, repeating the statement using the class separately from the case class definition, mitigate the problem

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)


def f(r:RDD[C]): String = "hello"
val in = sc.parallelize(List(C("hi1")))

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

f: (r: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[C])String
in: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[C] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:26

scala> f(in)
res2: String = hello
```

Comment: Well... I am not sure but I believe this problem has its roots in `serialization`. Try this again after making your type `C` `serializable`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh case classes are serializable by default.

Comment: @ShyamendraSolanki Yes that is... But in recent problems with `case class` +  `spark-shell`, sometimes simple `class` works. So... trying out a `serializable` `class` ( not a `case class` ) should be worth a try,

Comment: Also... For all my disappointment... I can not regenerate the problem. The above code works fine in my Spark-shell.

Comment: I have exactly the same behavior when using  a class extending `java.io.Serializable`. I use both spark 1.2 and 1.3, but my test is made with 1.3. I realized also that if I `:paste` the code with the case class definition separate from the function definition, I don't have the problem... But in other, more complicated cases, I'm pretty sure it fails...

Comment: note: I have actually had several problems when a case class is put in `:paste` environment together with definitions that use it, but it was not systematic so I though of something else. Errors like _value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(...,...)]_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is still an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5149). Code in spark-shell is wrapped in classes and it causes [strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762964/task-not-serializable-when-using-object-in-repl) sometimes.

The other problem: `Errors like value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(...,...)]` can be caused by using different versions of spark in the same project. If you use IntelliJ, go to *File -> Project Structure -> Libraries* and delete the stuff like "*SBT: org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.10:**1.1.0**:jar*". You need libs with spark's version 1.2.0 or 1.3.0.

Hope it will help you somehow.

Comment: I don't have any kind of project setup. I plainly launch the spark shell and send it keystrokes, hence I use always a single version of spark (or do I miss something?)

Comment: if you use spark 1.2.0 you should import these functions:  `Import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._ `, http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

Comment: I think you missunderstood. This problem I wrote about in my comment is also related to the repl and if the case class is put in the :paste environment alone or with another command. In some cases (I did not make a simple example yet), when I use the case class in a val, and paste it at the same time as the case class, I get this error rather than a clean execution (which would lead to some type mismatch afterward anyway...). But that was just a comment, and if it is related to this question, it is maybe not the same problem. I don't know if the second half of you answer should be here.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I've just tried to guess what could be wrong except this case class repl issue. I have no more guesses :(

Comment: np, thx for you answer! I should maybe make this problem a real question, rather than a comment, but it is so related it's almost a duplicate I think, just another symptom. I'll probably edit my question later, when I have the time to make a simple example.