# Databricks Apache Spark 1.4: Task not serializable (Scala)

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark

I have created two different Scala notebooks in databricks. One is calculating topics on the basis of LDA model and the other is just new fresh notebook without any prior calculations.

When I run the following code in 1st notebook:

```
val b = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3))
val c: Int = 4
def add (x:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]) = { x.map( n => n + c) }

add(b).collect()
```

I get "Task not serializable" error. When I run the same program in another notebook, it goes without problems.

Could anyone please suggest something?

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:293)
    at Notebook.add(<console>:71)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDA
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDA, value: org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDA@e9ea392)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: lda, type: class org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDA)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@6c9743ba)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@1a68799b)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC$$iwC@5abdbef3)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC@230d550a)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read@35d711b2)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $VAL2947, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd814.$read)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@25f85bf4)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read$$iwC$$iwC@d5ed125)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read$$iwC@dca05ea)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read@3f1acd5c)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $VAL2958, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8154.$read)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@45b864dc)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@5e9e8fc8)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@1e884b86)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@5e402ceb)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@25c3414e)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@229fc9e7)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@3ece12aa)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@7e3871b5)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@4e4a1d12)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@737adcd4)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC@4e8583f0)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC@ec97a95)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read@6bfa0665)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $VAL2973, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8155.$read)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@44fb0e14)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@4e127fe)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@5468a425)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@4442dbb1)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@17cf077d)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@612d11b5)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@4aee6cf4)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@6987d7f7)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@446be1f9)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@216afbd8)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC@669792e8)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC@8ba6572)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read@5725949f)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $VAL2987, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8158.$read)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@2da782a3)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@79a9a8ca)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@536a7276)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@b885215)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@14ccdc86)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@53d95ae)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
    - object (class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC@2741a6e0)
    - field (class: linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC, name: $iw, type: class linee339bfc6d4e74d779737c9ccd8c21fd8161.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC)
```

Comment: My first suggestion is that you provide the complete stack trace (or the relevant excerpts)

Comment: Right. Added 1st half (doesn't fit entirely)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's a bug of spark-shell console (the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768717/type-mismatch-with-identical-types-in-spark-shell/29781025#comment47714489_29781025)). It won't reproduce in your actual scala code submitted with `spark-submit`. The problem is in the closure: `map( n => n + c)`. Spark has to serialize and sent to every worker the value `c`, but `c` lives in some wrapped object in console. This object's behavior is *very strange* sometimes. For example, when i first run your example, i had the same errors. Then i used `val c = 4` instead of `val c: Int = 4` I've got no errors.

Unfortunately, I don't know the accurate workaround here. All I can suggest you is to wrap everything you want to use inside rdd transformations (map, filter, etc.) in object by yourself. For example:

```
scala> val b = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3))
b: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> object Foo { val c: Int = 4}
defined module Foo

scala> def add (x:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]) = { x.map( n => n + Foo.c) }
add: (x: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]

scala> add(b).collect()
....
res0: Array[Int] = Array(5, 6, 7)
```

Comment: Thanks. It become a little bit clearer now. And what to do if I want to use as "c" some other array calculated earlier?

Comment: The best way is to wrap it in broadcast data structure: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables . But If it's a result of computation over rdd's you might want to leave it as rdd, join with other rdd and use it. Or you can create case class object with field equals to you array and try to serialize it (similar with what i suggest in the answer).

Comment: Is there any reason why this broadcast may not work? I calculated topics for documents by LDA model, get array of topics and now want to use that array in further calculations. But I cannot neither broadcast it or wrap in object - in any case I get "not serializable" error..

Comment: I guess I can't say anything else useful with given information. "not serializable" means that there are some other fields in your wrapped object like `val field: RDD[..] = yourComputation` which can not be transfered to workers. Separate them from actual computation(just reassign to a variable in another object if you don't want to change already written code).